# How to show modalView from non UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have created a seperate class to handle loading data from a SqlServer. Right now I pass a search term to the object and it searches for the items in a database.

If it finds more than one item it needs to present a modalviewcontroller. The problem is that this is a NSObject and doesn't know about presenting modal views.

How can I present a modalviewcontroller from a NSObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delegate presenting the modal to a view controller - either by posting notifications on duplicates (gives you flexibility in which view controller presents) or defining a delegate protocol. This will keep your model separate from your view, preserving the MVC architecture of your app.

EDIT: using blocks for delegation is a fine approach in my view. I would just adjust your API to take a block to be performed in case of a duplicate, and have your modal take another block to handle the selection from many. That will probably give you maximum flexibility.

EDIT2: Based on understanding of your current API, I'd recommend this:

```
- (void)searchForItemWithString:(NSString *)searchString completionBlock:(librarianDidSelectItemBlock)block multiSelectBlock:(librarianMultiSelectBlock);
```

Furthermore I'd design your modal view controller to take a completion block as well.

Comment: I'm trying to keep this all in the object I made. I ended up making a reference to the app delegate and getting the rootviewcontroller to do it from there. What do you think of that solution?

Comment: @Hackmodford I don't think it's ideal. You've coupled your object to the app delegate and the app delegate's view controllers. But if you don't consider delegating the modal presentation to be an option, trying that is probably your best bet, although you might run into some visibility issues, depending.

Comment: I'm trying to use blocks instead of delegation. I've created an object that I call the librarian. The ViewController will ask the librarian to search for some items. The librarian (NSObject) will search and if it finds 1 it just returns the result to the block. If it finds more than one it needs to present a viewController to let the user choose an item, which then gets returned to the block. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Hackmodford I understand. I still think the view controllers should be responsible for the presentation and the selection from many. But it does sound like it might be a heavy lift to change that at this point.

Comment: This is what I'm using for search right now -(void)searchForItemWithString:(NSString *)searchString completionBlock:(librarianDidSelectItemBlock)block { Maybe I should add a parameter for the presentingViewController?

Comment: @Hackmodford yeah that's what I'd do.

Comment: I did it and it worked of course... add that as an answer and i'll mark it as solved. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Thanks but why would I want to have a different block for an immediate result and another block for when 1 of many was chosen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16561/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-hackmodford)